# Bootstrap navbar doesn't show properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am new to the StackOverFlow community and hope to contribute my own solutions in future :-) For now, your help will be appreciated:

This is a partial script for a Wordpress page using Bootstrap (with only the navbar part complete). For some reason, it doesn't show up properly on any browser except on Internet explorer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
 <meta charset="utf-8">

 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<meta name="Description" content="">
<meta name="Author" content="">
<link rel="icon" href="assets/img/favicon.ico">

  <title>Test</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS  EDITED-->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <!-- FontAwsome icons -->
  <link href="assets/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- google fonts -->
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <!-- HTML5 shiv and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

  </head>
 <body>

 <!-- HEADER ========   --> 
   <header class="site-header" role="banner">

      <!-- Navbar -->
      <div class="navbar-wrapper">
         <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

            <div class="container">

               <div class="navbar-header">
                   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="Boostrap to Wordpress"></a>

                </div><!--navbar header -->
                 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse"> 
                     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                       <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</li>
                       <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</li>
                       <li><a href="resources.html">Resources</li>
                       <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</li>
                     </ul><!-- nav

                 <div><!--navbar collapse -->

        </div><!-- container -->
    </div><!-- navbar -->
</div><!--navbar wrapper -->

   </header>

   <!-- Section1 ========   --> 
   <section>
   </section>

    <!--  sections missing ...  -->

    <!-- FOOTER ========   --> 

  <footer>
  </footer>

  <!-- BOOSTRAP CORE JAVASCRIPT  =====EDITED --> 
  <script assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 </body>
</html>
```

I am pretty sure that the CSS and JS scripts are up to date.

Comment: You have included `jquery.2.1.4.js` twice.. Remove one link!!

Comment: Check The error in console window. I am sure bootstrap is not loaded correctly

Comment: I'll check it out and report the results.

Comment: Many thanks to Guruprasad Rao who answered my question, and to you too Ravi Kumar Mistry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include bootstrap file properly and check if it has been loaded and remove multiple reference to `jquery.js` and keep any one either from `cdn` - `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js` or from your local - `assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
 <meta charset="utf-8">

 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<meta name="Description" content="">
<meta name="Author" content="">
<link rel="icon" href="assets/img/favicon.ico">

  <title>Test</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
 

  <!-- FontAwsome icons -->
  <link href="assets/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- google fonts -->
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <!-- HTML5 shiv and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->

  </head>
 <body>

 <!-- HEADER ========   --> 
   <header class="site-header" role="banner">
      
   <!-- Navbar -->
   <div class="navbar-wrapper">
         <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

            <div class="container">

               <div class="navbar-header">
                   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="Boostrap to Wordpress"></a>

    </div><!--navbar header -->
                 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse"> 
                     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</li>
                       <li><a href="resources.html">Resources</li>
                       <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</li>
      </ul><!-- nav

                 <div><!--navbar collapse -->

      </div><!-- container -->
 </div><!-- navbar -->
</div><!--navbar wrapper -->

   </header>

   <!-- Section1 ========   --> 
   <section>
   </section>

 <!--  sections missing ...  -->

 <!-- FOOTER ========   --> 

  <footer>
  </footer>

  <!-- BOOSTRAP CORE JAVASCRIPT  ======== Place at the end of the document so the pages load faster --> 
   
  

 </body>
</html>
```